# php echo other php code

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to have php code that contains an echo. within that echo however, I need it to echo php code within it. a short example is bellow.

```
<!php echo '<?php echo "test"; ?>'; ?>
```

My main reason for this is that I will be using a mysql_fetch_array while loop that echoes out some html and $row[] information in it but also needs php in it. Bellow I have put what I actually need to be done.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<div style="position: relative;" >
<img src="Backgrounds/'. $row[id] .'.jpg" alt="error">
<br /><br />
<?php
Some php content that also uses $row[] content
?>
<br />
</div>';
}
```

My only problem is that when I inspect element in chrome, it turns out like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<div style="position: relative;" >
<img src="Backgrounds/'. $row[id] .'.jpg" alt="error">
<br /><br />
<!--?php
Some php content that also uses $row[] content
?-->
<br />
</div>';
}
```

and it turns the php part into comments for html. Im not sure what to do here.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Why do you want php code to be executed? `eval` is probably what you want. http://php.net/eval

Comment: @CharlotteDunois "NoOne" really wants evil in this context ;)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think he wants to print out php examples rather than execute php code. This was just my interpretation though.

Comment: @Rawr Poorly described then.

Comment: In the end @CharlotteDunois has the right interpretation of OP's question. Oh well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise, try reversing it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    ?>
    <div style="position: relative;" >
        <img src="Backgrounds/<?=$row[id]?>.jpg" alt="error">
        <br /><br />
        <?php
            //Some php content that also uses $row[] content
        ?>
        <br />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And also switch to PDO objects.

Comment: thanks. this works for what I want. I will work on the PDO stuff later.

Answer (score 2):

In a html context, `<?php`, `<something`, etc, is the opening of a html tag. Edit `<` with his html entity `&lt;` to prevent it happening..

```
&lt;?php
```

Even better, use htmlspecialchars:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<?php echo "test"; ?>'); ?>
```

Comment: do i do the same with the end also? like ?&lt;

Comment: The **lt** in &lt; stands for **less than** which is the < symbol. If you want the greater than sign then you'd use &gt;

Comment: the &lt; and &gt; symbols for some reason put it into quotes and then displays all the inside php on the screen while the htmlspecialcharacters outputs all the code inside it on the screen